# force graphs legend/key to a specific size

Tags: gnuplot

i want to generate some plots from my data that i want to include in some documentation.
I put the box outside the graph area.
the problem is that for different plots the box has different sizes so also the graph area changes its size. this looks very messy in the document becasue the plots are vertical aligned.

I am searching for a way to fix the size of the box to some width that is appropriate for all plots but i could not found a way to do so. 
the `set key` command has a width parameter but it seems not to do that one would expect from such a parameter.

It would be grat if someone could help.

thanks
vlad

Comment: One way would be to fix the size of the graph area instead, using e.g. `set rmargin screen 0.8` (if the key is on the right side).

Comment: @Christoph the width of the key box still toggles

Comment: If you have a box around the key (`set key box`), I see no easy way to achieve this. You would need to adjust the `width` option for every key such that `lengh of longest entry + width` is a constant.

Comment: @Christoph even without border the key itself is glued to the right side of the window. since it is right of the graph it is reversed so that the samples are next to the graph. but because of that the sample column moves dependent of key string length. faking the key title lengths seems to be the only option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got the correct impression of what you want. Consider the following example

```
reset

set multiplot layout 2,1

set rmargin screen 0.7
set key reverse Left left top at screen 0.72, graph 1

plot sin(x), cos(x) t 'long title'

plot sin(x), cos(x) t 'very long title'
unset multiplot
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Both the samples and the text do not move. You must only set an appropriate `rmargin`. `left` and `top` is the key box alignment regarding the position specified with `at ...`, although these settings are default, I explicitely included them for clarity. `Left` is the alignment of the entry text.

Comment: i have no multiplot since i want the single plots in multiple image files. But thanks using that way of absolute positioning does work

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I know, that you don't have `multiplot`, but it was the best way to show the effect.